# Vue 3 Validate Optional api typscript

Tags: vue.js, validation

For some reason the vue 3 screams on v$.form.email.$errors
**it's saying that form.email doesn't have $errors but in run time it does working**.
how can i fix this issue?, i know that i need to let know the useVuelidate the type.

```
setup() {
    return { v$: useVuelidate() };
  },
return {
      form: {
      email: "",
      password: "",
     }
    };

validations() {
    return {
     form: {
      email: {
        required,
        email,
      },
      password: {
        required,
        min: minLength(6),
      },
     }
    };
```

Html code where the error marked as red:

```
<small
            class="error-msg"
                                                   // here
            v-for="(error, index) of v$.form.email.$errors"
            :key="index"
          >
```

[image]

[image]

If you remove the form and keep just email and password then the typescript has no errors.

- In run time both of them are working

Comment: "useVuelidate" - are you using Vuelidate? This should be mentioned. The question is very specific to it. This `v$form..email.$errors`, and `},
return {
      form: {`  this isn't valid code. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can reproduce the problem

Comment: v$.form.email.$errors - it saying there is no $errors property

Comment: The code is still invalid. Check return statement. It's not known how `form` is defined. Also `validations` is is for Vuelidate 0.x and Vue 2, it isn't supposed to be workable with `useVuelidate`. Check how `useVuelidate` is used in docs.

Comment: I don't want to use composition api at the moment

Comment: I stand corrected regarding `validations`, it wasn't available with `useVuelidate` before but is ok now. You're already using composition API, it's `setup`. Please, provide MCVE that can reproduce the problem, it's impossible to answer the question without knowing what you did wrong. It's likely there's no `form`, etc component data, so there is nothing do validate. It also depends on Vuelidate versions because it's unstable.

Comment: it's very simple, everything is working on run time.

Comment: it just the typescript doesn't know that form.email.$errors exist.

Comment: if i would do:
return {
      email: "",
      password: "",
    };

Comment: and the same in validation and it would work in compile time

Comment: I see, so there is TS error. "vue 3 screams" isn't the best description of the problem. You already use composition API with `setup`. I'd suggest to just use it for the rest of component definition. Composition solves several problems, one of them is poor TS support in options API. This isn't only reason why composition appeared but a big one. A dirty fix is to type $v with `any` or anything closer to its real structure.